# How to add own form field to instance from models form?

Tags: python, django

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST,
                               instance=Example.objects.get(user=request.user))
    except:
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        m = form.save(commit=False)
        is_ok = request.POST.get('is_ok')
        m.is_ok = is_ok
        m.user = request.user
        m.save()
```

How to add field `is_ok` to `instance=Example.objects.get(user=request.user)`

Note: I can not add this field to the model forms.

If I change existing data, my `is_ok` value changes to default

EDIT:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="is_ok" id="id_is_ok"/>
```

If this input is disabled, my `is_ok = request.POST.get('is_ok')` = None

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean my add that field to that assignment. Please can you clarify this a bit better?

Comment: Your question is not clarify. Can you put your model codes

Comment: What do you expect after m.save()? Do you expect that django creates new field is_ok in table for Example model in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should do this in the declaration of your ExampleForm class. I assume the class looks something like this

```
from your_app.models import ExampleModel
from django.forms import ModelForm

class ExampleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
```

You just need to declare the field on the form. Something like -

```
class ExampleForm(ModelForm)
    is_ok = forms.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
```

The form class will now handle the creation of the `input` element for the `is_ok` field, just as it does for all the other fields, but it will override the settings on the Model - it won't be disabled any more (see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets) for more info).